# Css Grid maximize space between elements if space greater than minimum grid gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid. I would like the elements in the grid to have a minimum grid gap of 35 px. I would like the elements to have a maximum width of 286 pixels. If the space between elements is greater than 35 pixels, I would like the space between elements to be the maximum. I created a picture below to illustrate what I want.

The green shows the grid.
The blue shows the minimum gap between boxes, After the gap get's below this grid, the boxes should go on a new line or start shrinking.

Currently I am getting the result on top, but I would like the result on the bottom. I want the elements to be pushed to the sides of the grid. Currently there is extra space between the right most element and the grid.

[image]

This is the code I'm using which currently produces these results

```
.container: {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 35;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(286px, 1fr));
},
```

Comment: Not possible with Css-grid. This is a flexbox item

Comment: Plz, provide the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize space between content use [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

```
.container {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```